# ASP.Net: Record image displays via CDN

Tags: asp.net, lightbox, ashx

On my site, I display an image after the user clicks on a thumbnail (opens in a lightbox). I want to store the number of times users open the images.

I was thinking of something like pointing to an ASHX page that generates the image and updates the DB with the view count, but this can't be done since this is a remote file from a CDN. I can't just count the thumbnail clicks, since the image opens in lightbox.

Can anybody suggest a way I can accomplish what I'm trying?

Thanks,
WT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using javascript to open the image in the lightbox just add some code to make an ajax call at that point to your ashx handler.  The handler should just record that the image has been viewed.

Comment: The problem with that is that upon clicking, the lightbox opens. The user can see the other images through the lightbox, which won't be recorded.

Comment: @WildThing ~ Does the user use buttons to navigate left and right? Is the lightbox code yours?

Comment: Yes, the user can use buttons to navigate left/right. I have used a 3rd party lightbox component.

Comment: @Wild Thing: The lightbox is still javascript, right?  You can modify the navigation to do whatever you want.  In this case you just need to inject a little bit of code to make the call to your handler.

Comment: Incidentally, can't you get usage statistics from your CDN?  Seems to me that they should be able to provide you with exactly the type of information you are looking for.

Comment: @Chris - Yup, I know, but the JS is minified and packed, and I didn't want to create a patch into the code, unless I had to. I might have to do just that. The CDN does provide logs, but these image access statistics need to be part of the website administration section, for reporting purposes.

Comment: @Wild Thing: I really don't see another way, unless the lightbox you are using provides event handlers you can plug into to do something as part of the navigation.  I'm pretty sure a couple of them do.

Comment: @Chris: yeah, starting to look that way...the documentation on this particular component is pretty light (leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/), but it shouldn't be too difficult to tie into the event handlers with jquery or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a javascript call to the thumbnail click and have that call back to the server to increment the count.

Comment: As per my reply to Chris above, upon clicking on the thumbnail, the lightbox opens. The user can see the other images through the lightbox, which won't be recorded.

Comment: If you want to track how many times an image is viewed then server logs are probably the best way to go. You could look at periodically (daily?) importing data from the CDN - depending on what they make available.